# c# i'm not editing my collection,but the program show me InvalidOperationException error

Tags: c#, invalidoperationexception

I don't understand why this code does not work.

```
 foreach (DataRow dr in dtr.Rows)
        {
            A = new Kustom.Metier.Authentification.Utilisateur(Convert.ToInt32(dr[0]), dr[1].ToString().Trim(), dr[2].ToString().Trim(), Convert.ToBoolean(dr[3]), _droitDal.getDroits(Convert.ToInt32(dr[0])));
            list.Add(A);
        }
```

Comment: Can you inform what you are trying to do with this? and is this custom function or an inbuilt function?

Comment: i'm trying to create a list of objects named "utilisateur"

Comment: Are utilisateur and _droitDal.getDroits custom functions? Did you try to debug and check where is the exact issue - in this code or the mentioned functions?

Comment: @OhBeWise, the `DataRow` class does not have a value property on its item collection. It has a `.Item(n)` property that is also the default property.  So calling `dr[0]` is like calling `dr.Item(0)`.  No `.Value` needed: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwfe1t7z(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @ps2goat Correct. I mistook `DataRow` for `DataGridViewRow` in my haste. But I realized my error and already deleted the comment.

Comment: I don't think there is enough information in the question to diagnose this problem. 

The only things I could see are possible null values being passed in. A Conversion to a type that isn't possible, you were wrong about what was in each column or it is not matching the list type when it is created.

I would set a break point and loop until it fails but something being null seems like a strong possibility.